# mini ITX hdd too close to PSU magnetic field could damage it?

Tags: power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a (notebook) hard drive be affected by magnets, such as those in a headphone or a cell phone'?](https://superuser.com/questions/183488/can-a-notebook-hard-drive-be-affected-by-magnets-such-as-those-in-a-headphone)

All miniITX cases i've seen have PSU really close to HDD placement.

In my case it's sitting right over the PSU.

Now electricity means magnetic fields, and HDDS don't like that.

I'm worried it will kill my new 1tb drive very soon -

any ideas thoughts on this?

Should I be worried?

Comment: They are shielded.  You understand that mini-itx cases are used a lot
?

Comment: HDDs are shielded or PSUs?

Comment: my question has nothing to do with the question you linked. PSU magnetic field will be much bigger than of a headphone.

Comment: @Sandro: An answer to that question is directly relevant to your question: "The only magnets powerful enough to scrub data from a drive platter are laboratory degaussers" with references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. There's two factors in play here - firstly, both the PSU and HDD have metal cases that act as [shielding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding). In addition the strength of magnetic fields necessary to affect a hard drive is fairly large (there are EXTREMELY strong magnets inside the hard drive after all) and would need to be directed.

Practically speaking, if something was to produce the an EM field powerful enough to alter the contents of a hard drive, you'd have to worry about other things ;p